# Sending a stored value register over serial in assembly and 8051

Tags: assembly, serial-port, 8051

I'd like to send via serial port port using an 8051 microprocessor and assembly code, values contained in the processor register.

Some strange chars appear on HyperTerminal, while sending strings works good. 
Ideas?

Comment: Why not just convert the register values to hex ASCII strings before sending them ?

Comment: Yes, it sounds not so immediate achieve that

Answer (score 0):

3 candiates

1. Most likely: The strange character you received in hyper-term are in fact the data your 8051 is sending.  Since the 8051 may send bytes with code 128 - 255, the area outside the ASCII as well as unprintable ASCII in range of 0 - 31 (except 10,13), hyper-term is using some *interesting* characters to display these bytes.  e. g. Partial code character table follows.  Note other code to character mappings exist.

128 €
129 ?
130 ‚
131 ƒ
132 „
133 …
134 †
135 ‡
136 ˆ
137 ‰

1. Sender/receiver are not using the same parity/stop/bit length settings.  Insure both are using the same number of bits/word (8), stop bits (1) and parity setting (suggest "none").
2. Mis-match baud.  Unusual but the 8051 *may* be using transmit baud different from receive baud.  (not likely)

---

Questions for further investigation

A. Detail how you know the sending strings work good.

B. What were the expected characters to receive and what strange character did you receive?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was trying to send register contained stored value in an incorrect way, causing a bad decoding over the client. Other values are ok!

Answer (score 0):

```
org 0h
mov a,#10110011b
mov r2,#8d
clr P2.2
     rrc a
     mov p2.2,c
     djnz r2,go
    setb p2.2
end
```